# UI Test for AVFoundation's Camera

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I'm trying to create a UI test for QR reader. I'm using AVFoundation's barcode types to decode QR. When user pressed the button QR Reader will appear. If the camera captures QR code with the correct form it has to present another view. How can I test it? Should I create UI test?

I've created Unit Testing for decoding QR function but I need to create a scenario for presenting other View Controller if camera decodes QR code which is in correct form.

Comment: So, the problem is that you don't know how to refer to your other View Controller in `XCTestCase` ?

Comment: actually I want to scan a QR code as a test then check if it present the other view or not?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get it to scan a QR code easily in your tests. What would be sensible to do is to pass in a launch argument when you start your UI test, then have your code in the app check for that launch argument and mimic a successful scan. After that your apps logic will continue as normal. It won't test the actual scan process but theres not much you can do about that outside of covering it with unit tests.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments